# Unity 3d error while opening the editor. Probably an error in the package manager

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am facing a problem with unity 3d editor. The issue is in both the versions of the Editor that I have downloaded being 2021 version and 2019.4 version. It occurs whenever I create and load up a new project in the unity editor.I have made no changes in the script or the scene so it is probably a problem with the packages. The module I have downloaded is the android build support and windows build support. Moreover I do not get any error message. I am attaching a screenshot. Please check the screenshot and please see what is the problem. Please help is you can. I will be very thankful[Please see the picture and Help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpQ3X.png)